# Raspberry Pi live stream through webcam to android phone

Tags: pi-2, streaming-video, webcam

I am trying to broadcast video from web cam connect with Raspberry Pi to Android app, for that I used 'motion', by this it can stream video over local network only, using http://RPi_addr:port

but now I want to stream video from RPi to anywhere(remotely) and I have no idea how to do that please give some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to stream video over internet with RPi?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24158/best-way-to-stream-video-over-internet-with-rpi)

Comment: actually it's not, I am trying to stream form RPi to other network which can be anywhere, I've done it with local network

Comment: Use your Public IP. Just forward port to the RPi device. You can do it on your router using this site: http://portforward.com/

Comment: @Huczu thanx for suggestion, I don't know much about it. So can you please tell me, is it possible if RPi used dongle(Huawei) so its IP is different then router's IP

Comment: Yes it is. Each device in network has different local IP. Router IP is smth like 192.168.0.1/192.168.1.1/.1.10/0.10 You can check it in instruction. Port forwarding can be done only on router. You don't need to configure RPi for that. Maybe just configure IP in aplication.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to port forward your Pi on your router. To do this, follow **these steps:**

On a laptop or PC running Windows, open Command Prompt and type '**ipconfig**'. Look for your Ethernet or WiFi adapter. Note down the **Gateway** address. Next, go into your browser and enter that address. If prompted for a user name/password, look on the bottom/side/back of router for this. Once logged in, look for "Applications & Gaming" or similar. Find the "Port Forwarding" tab. You may need to look up specific instructions for your router. Then, add the IP address of the Pi in the "Local IP" box. For internal ports, put what you use to connect to the motion stream. For external, you can pick whatever. If there is an option for TCP/UDP, select TCP. Enable it if there is an option for "Enable". Save changes.

Now, you need your WAN IP. Simply go to "whatismyip.org" and note down that address.

Finally, type the WAN IP and your Port (separated by a : colon) and hit enter. The stream should show up, but if your upload speed is slow the stream may lag. Also check with your Internet Service Provider (ISP) to see if hosting a stream is within your Terms Of Service.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanx for information, but I want to know that is it useful if I moved RPi to other network?

Comment: @RaThOd If the Pi is port forwarded on one network (yours), and you connect it to another network (your friends), you won't be able to access it using your IP address because your router has nothing to forward. Unless you port forward the other router, or are on the same network, your phone won't be able to access the Pi unless it is on your home network.

Comment: Thanx but if I want to make it remotely ( work in any network) what should I have to do?

Comment: @RaThOd As long as the Pi is on the network you port forwarded (home network), any device from anywhere can connect to it. Once the Pi is off that network, i.e. You take it on vacation, nothing can connect to it unless it is on LAN on a separate network.    In short, keep it at home and you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing better than [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) with its support for WebRTC for streaming over internet.

Comment: read the doc better ,that's not a command, that's a repo line you have to add to a sources.list

Answer (score -1):

Check out Motioneye for Raspberry pi - https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos &

He has both web-fronted app & complete OS for Raspberry pi !!

And I would recommend you to try [weaved service](https://www.weaved.com/raspberry-pi-remote-connection/) for streaming the feed through internet it is free for a limited usage & **NO port forwarding** just install the service and start using the service!! It is a pretty good.You can install weaved and just select the port that motioneye is running . And finally you can use your android browser to view the feed the web interface is well customized for mobile devices !